# Using minted to highlight Mako templates

Tags: minted, pygments

When attempting to use the `minted` package to highlight a piece of source code in the Mako templating language:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{mako}
<%inherit file='base'/>

% for i in range(5):
  ${i}
% endfor
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I find that the `file='base'` fragment is coloured red -- indicating an error.  I suspect this is due to the underlying Pygments library having incomplete support for Mako (the code itself is 100% valid).  What I am wondering is how I can redefine the error fragment to hide this.

Comment: If the fault is in the Pygments support for Mako, this is not a question about TeX and friends.

Comment: @egreg: "What I am wondering is how I can redefine the error fragment to hide this." So accepting that we get bad output redefining the command that indicates a piece of text is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `.pygtex` file that's produced:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYGborland{c+cp}{\PYGborlandZlt{}\PYGborlandZpc{}}\PYGborland{n+nb}{inherit} \PYGborland{err}{file=\PYGborlandZsq{}base\PYGborlandZsq{}}\PYGborland{c+cp}{/\PYGborlandZgt{}}

\PYGborland{c+cp}{\PYGborlandZpc{}} \PYGborland{k}{for} \PYGborland{n}{i} \PYGborland{o+ow}{in} \PYGborland{n+nb}{range}\PYGborland{p}{(}\PYGborland{l+m+mi}{5}\PYGborland{p}{):}
\PYGborland{x}{  }\PYGborland{c+cp}{\PYGborlandZdl{}\PYGborlandZob{}}\PYGborland{n}{i}\PYGborland{c+cp}{\PYGborlandZcb{}}
\PYGborland{c+cp}{\PYGborlandZpc{}}\PYGborland{k}{ endfor}
\end{Verbatim}
```

If you want to treat the part marked `\PYGborland{err}` like `inherit`, then you can make

```
\PYGborland@tok@err
```

equivalent to `\PYGborland@tok@n+nb`, that can be obtained only with `\csname`; with `etoolbox` it's easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}

\csletcs{PYGborland@tok@err}{PYGborland@tok@n+nb}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{mako}
<%inherit file='base'/>

% for i in range(5):
  ${i}
% endfor
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]